# Application Constants and webservice URL in App.xaml in Windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

Sorry I m new to this..

In App.xaml which section we can add Application Constants and webservice URL in Windows phone 7.

I need to perform only Get(read) operation to access these values in application.

Can anyone provide sample code for that.

Comment: couldnt you just make a class to hold that constants?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `Application.Resources` node to introduce application wide `StaticResource`s. Eg;

```
<Application xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
  <Application.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="SomeImportantConstant">SomeValue</system:String>
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

You can then use this in your XAML elsewhere in your code like so...

```
<TextBlock Text="{StaticResource SomeImportantConstant}" />
```

For certain things that are usually done in XAML this can be a nicer alternative to static class containing constants. A WP7 relevant example: I use this to store my Bing Maps Application ID. I can then bind the value from a `StaticResource` where I declare my `Map`. Bit cleaner then having to mix in code-behind to reference a constant value.

Comment: Thanks for reply MrMDavidson ..A Question, how can I access the SomeImportantConstant in code Behind (xaml.cs) ?

Comment: I got it by using                                                          var MyValue= App.Current.Resources["SomeImportantConstant"];                      or                                                                string MyVal= (string)Application.Current.Resources["SomeImportantConstant"];